# run select query on multiple tables in the same db

Tags: mysql, select, information-schema

I have 15 tables in my database.

I want to run a select query on all the 15 tables. Something like this:

```
select count(*) from (SELECT Table_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'my_table_schema' ) where ratings > 10;
```

Tables that look like this (not all tables have `ratings` column):

```
Users Table

UserID | Rating
12345  | 23
12346  | 5
```

```
Movies Table

MovieID | Rating
44444  | 43
32345  | 43
12346  | 5
```

```
Federations Table

FederationID | Rating
22444  | 13
12345  | 130
45346  | 50
```

I'm looking for an expected outcome like this

```
Movies - 2
Users - 1
Federations - 3
...
...
...
```

Edit: updated the description to 15 tables from 3 tables.

Comment: What's wrong with a) 3 queries or b) UNION?

Comment: updated the description, 
I actually have 15 tables, not sure if having 15 queries is helpful, if I can do it using just one query

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of tables, you can use `union all`:

```
select 'movies' as who, count(*) as cnt from movies where rating > 10
union all select 'users', count(*) from users where rating > 10
union all select 'federations', count(*) from federations where rating > 10
```

If you want to do this dynamically, then you need a prepared statement. In MySQL, it looks like:

```
set @sql = null;
select @sql = group_concat(
    'select ''', table_name, ''' as who, count(*) as cnt from `', table_name, '` where rating > 10'
     separator ' union all '
)
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'my_table_schema';

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

This will fail if any of the tables in `my_table_schema` does not have a column called `rating`, which is why I doubt that's really a good idea.

Comment: thats a good point, yes all the tables do not have `rating` column, is there a way for me to check only if there is `rating` column, then use that table.